# Creating Decision Tree and doing Hyperparameter tuning R?

Tags: r

Very new to modeling with R. I want to create a Decision Tree and do hyperparameter tuning on the parameters and have the model output what the optimal hyperparameters are. After doing this, I would like to fit the model using these parameters.

Coming from a Python background, GridSearchCV was very straightforward and does exactly this. Looking at the documentation, I am lost on how to set the grid of parameters. Here is my code so far:

```
train_matrix <- Matrix(as.matrix(train[, var_selected_train]),
                   sparse = TRUE)

test_matrix <- Matrix(as.matrix(test[, var_selected_test]),
                   sparse = TRUE)


dtree <- tune.rpart(target~., data = train_matrix, minsplit = c(5,10,15,20), maxdepth = c(1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30))

summary(dtree)
```

First, I am not sure what to put for the "function" argument so from my research, I concluded that that was the response varaible. var_selected_train and var_selected_test are the actual columns that I have selected out of the dataframe(s).

Am I on the right track? Any help would be great!

Comment: You can always find help by typing `?functionname`.

Comment: You may feel more comfortable going with the `rml` package, which feels similar to pythons way of doing things: https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/tune.html